# Azure Policy Definition to prohibit creation of a VM above certain cost per month?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, policy, whitelist

Is there a way to define a policy in an Azure subscription that will block the creation of any virtual machine with a cost above a certain amount? I have tried defining a policy that whitelists or blacklists individual SKU's, but it's tedious to maintain, to say the least.

Comment: Why it’s tedious with `skus`? If possible, can you post the code? I don’t think cost is directly reflected in the control-plane API. So, chances are little bleak. If you find an Alias for cost in resource blade, it’s possible.

Comment: After some investigation this morning, I see costs can be fetched by resource type with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices) api. However, it's not `https://management.azure.com`, it's `https://prices.azure.com`. Would be interesting to see if management API policies can be integrated with external APIs. I couldn't find much documentation anywhere..

Comment: Surprising that Azure makes it to tedious to work with pricing. This is a key issue when trying to implement cost management controls.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

PART 1:

In the Azure Portal, select the "Policy" service
In the policy service, select "definitions", add policy definition
Populate the definition as follows:

BASICS
Location:   (select subscription)
Name:       deny high-cost CPU VMs
Category:   custom

POLICY RULE:
{
"mode": "Indexed",

```
"policyRule": {
  "if": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
      },
      {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/sku.name",
        "in": "[parameters('listOfDeniedSKUs')]"
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "Deny"
  }
},

"parameters": {
  "listOfDeniedSKUs": {
    "type": "Array",
    "metadata": {
      "description": "The list of size SKUs that are denied for virtual machines.",
      "displayName": "Denied Size SKUs",
      "strongType": "VMSKUs"
    }
  }
}
```

}

PART 2:
Wait a little while until the policy shows up on the definitions list.
In the policy service, select "assignments", assign policy.

BASICS
Policy definition: Select the above policy

Policy
Select all sizes except for the sizes you want to allow

PART 3:
Review monthly and select any new SKUs you want to deny